# pymongo extend list with list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In the mongo command line, you can extend a list with another list by doing

```
> db.mycol.update({"user":"_dummy_"},{"$addToSet":{"someList":{"$each":["a","b"]}}})
```

Take example set ["x","y"], this got correctly extended to ["x","y","a","b"]

I tried the following code to do the same using pymongo:

```
col = db.mycol
col.update({"user":"_dummy_"},{"$addToSet":{"someList":{"$each":["a","b"]}}})
```

Which I expected to have the same result. However, the result I got was:
["x","y","$each":"a,b"]

What would be the correct way of doing this with pymongo?

**note** If the syntax differs between python 2 and 3, I'm using 3.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, my code read ["a","b"] as a string instead of a list. The bugfix there also fixed this code. So the code I tried does work the way it should, but only if I provide a list, even if it's only 1 element